# Error happens when compiling lib from *-rpc.discovery file on iOS

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, google-app-engine

I have tried this one [https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume%5fios) to compile and generate lib on iOS but it still print the error:

"ERROR: Parameter 'userId' has objcName 'userId' and so did something else."

Here is my discovery file which is generated from eclipse: https://mega.co.nz/#!45p2nZZD!KTwFr2Kbqgron4oEHBZHojUpsiqLAAyZhTCbANnbYjA

Can someone help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but putting this here in the hopes of helping others. I just tracked this down by putting Xcode breakpoints in the Google service generator... crazy. This error is happening because your Java endpoint has both an @Named annotation and a parameter with the same name.

So you've got both this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "someMethod", path = "whatever")
public void blah( @Named ("THEPROBLEM") String foo ) throws ServiceException { .... }
```

and this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "anotherMethod", path = "whatever")
public void blah( @Named ("bar") String THEPROBLEM ) throws ServiceException { .... }
```